# How does PostgreSQL perform ORDER BY with a b-tree index on the field?

Tags: postgresql, sorting, indexing, sql-order-by, postgresql-performance

I have a table `bsort`:

```
CREATE TABLE bsort(a int, data text);
```

Here `data` may be incomplete. In other words, some tuples may not have `data` value.

And then I build a b-tree index on the table:

```
CREATE INDEX ON bsort USING BTREE(a);
```

Now if I perform this query:

```
SELECT * FROM bsort ORDER BY a;
```

Does PostgreSQL sort tuples with nlogn complexity, or does it get the order directly from the b-tree index?

Comment: Check the execution plan and you'll see

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a simple query like this Postgres will use an [**index scan**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index-scanning.html) and retrieve readily sorted tuples from the index in order. Due to its [MVCC model](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc-intro.html) Postgres had to always visit the "heap" (data pages) additionally to verify entries are actually visible to the current transaction. Quoting the [Postgres Wiki on index-only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans):

> PostgreSQL indexes do not contain visibility information. That is, it
> is not directly possible to ascertain if any given tuple is visible to
> the current transaction, which is why it has taken so long for index-only
> scans to be implemented.

Which finally happened in version **9.2**: **[index-only scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html)**. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index-scanning.html)

> If the index stores the original indexed data values (and not some
> lossy representation of them), it is useful to support [**index-only scans**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html), in which the index returns the actual data not just the `TID` of
> the heap tuple. This will only avoid I/O if the visibility map shows
> that the `TID` is on an all-visible page; else the heap tuple must be
> visited anyway to check MVCC visibility. But that is no concern of the
> access method's.

The **[visibility map](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-vm.html)** decides whether index-only scans are possible. Only an option if all involved column values are included in the index. Else, the heap has to be visited (additionally) in any case. *The sort step is still not needed.*

That's why we sometimes append otherwise useless columns to indexes now. Like the `data` column in your example:

```
CREATE INDEX ON bsort (a, data);  -- btree is the default index type
```

It makes the index bigger (depends) and a bit more expensive to maintain and use for other purposes. So only append the `data` column if you get index-only scans out of it. The order of columns in the index is important:

- [Working of indexes in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6115/3684)
- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

Since Postgres 11, there are also "covering indexes" with the `INCLUDE` keyword. Like:

```
CREATE INDEX ON bsort (a) INCLUDE (data);
```

See:

- [Does a query with a primary key and foreign keys run faster than a query with just primary keys?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/207938/3684)

The benefit of an index-only scan, [per documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-VISIBILITY-MAP)

> If it's known that all tuples on the page are visible, the heap fetch
> can be skipped. This is most noticeable on large data sets where the
> visibility map can prevent disk accesses. The visibility map is vastly
> smaller than the heap, so it can easily be cached even when the heap
> is very large.

The visibility map is maintained by [**`VACUUM`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-vacuum.html) which happens automatically if you have [autovacuum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-autovacuum.html) running (the default setting in modern Postgres). Details:

- [Are regular VACUUM ANALYZE still recommended under 9.1?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/18664/3684)

But there is some delay between write operations to the table and the next `VACUUM` run. The gist of it:

- Read-only tables stay ready for index-only scans once vacuumed.
- Data pages that have been modified lose their "all-visible" flag in the visibility map until the next `VACUUM` (and all older tansactions being finished), so it depends on the ratio between write operations and `VACUUM` frequency.

Partial index-only scans are still possible if *some* of the involved pages are marked all-visible. But if the heap has to be visited anyway, the access method "index scan" is a bit cheaper. So if too many pages are currently dirty, Postgres will switch to the cheaper index scan altogether. [The Postgres Wiki again](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans#What_types_of_queries_may_be_satisfied_by_an_index-only_scan.3F):

> As the number of heap fetches (or "visits") that are projected to be
> needed by the planner goes up, the planner will eventually conclude
> that an index-only scan isn't desirable, as it isn't the cheapest
> possible plan according to its cost model. The value of index-only
> scans lies wholly in their potential to allow us to elide heap access
> (if only partially) and minimise I/O.

Comment: Worth noting the complexities of trying to order by different collations as well, perhaps, as ordering of character data is rather more complex. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-collations.html

Comment: @DavidAldridge: This is relevant, of course, but only if `ORDER BY` involves a character type column, which is not the case in this example. The added `data` column has type `text`, but `ORDER BY` only lists the `integer` column `a`, so collation rules are of no concern.

Comment: Quite so, but I didn't think that you'd fancy answering another question that was exactly the same except that it uses a TEXT column ;)

Comment: @DavidAldridge: Hence, your comment is a valuable addition.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter . . . I'm tempted to say that your answers are always interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to check the execution plan.  But, Postgres is quite capable of using the index to make the `order by` more efficient.  It would read the records directly from the index.  Because you have only one column, there is no need to access the data pages.

Comment: What if the table has more than one column? Will it still read records from the index?

Comment: That would be a different question, but it should.  It then needs to go back to the data pages to get the rest of the columns.