# postgresql - are my indexes or column types slowing down my query?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a table I created locally to use some of PG's window functions on a dataset that has about 4 million rows (originally a text file). Each row corresponds to a customer order.

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
  orderid integer,
  customerid integer,
  orderdate date,
  status text,
  amount money,
  tax money,
  customername text,
  customerstate text
```

I have the database running locally in a i7 8gb RAM Windows 8 machine. I have btree indexes (indices?) on orderid, customerid and orderdate.

When I run the following query, it takes 300 seconds (appx). I was hoping with some basic tuning I could get it down to a minute, but I'm not a DBA. Anyone have tips?

```
select orderid, customername, orderdate, 
rank() OVER (PARTITION BY customername ORDER BY orderdate ASC) as cust_ord_nbr
from orders
```

Comment: why user customername as the partition key when you have a customerid in the table?

Comment: @DanielVérité - down to 198 seconds now :-)

Comment: How many different customers are there ?

Comment: @wildplasser - 3.3 million

Comment: In that case, normalising customers into a separate table will not help (much) The only thing that could possibly help would then be a composite index on (customerid, orderdate)

Comment: @wildplasser - thanks, that got me down to 140 seconds. Curious - is the speed due to my hardware? Further, is it CPU, RAM or some other thing? What if I had a datastore 10x this size - just 'wait'?

Comment: Possibly just the sheer volume of the data: approx 4M * ~100 ~= 400MB of data. Try prefixing the command with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to get the time required for the query *without* the output.

Comment: What's your use case? A human client wouldn't be interested in receiving 4 mio. rows at once. Are you writing to another table? I don't see any constraints, can you provide the exact table definition (what you get with `\d orders` in psql)?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - no production use case, mainly data auditing prep before further transformation and analysis.

Comment: Which columns do you *need* in the result? Do you need `customername` or would `customerid` do the job as well? Where do you send the result? You don't just query 4 mio rows, you have to put the result *somewhere*. Is it a read-only table? Are you the only user? Or do you have (concurrent) write access, too? Consider instructions for [postgresql-performance] questions: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Covering index

Partition by `customerid`, like [@Daniel commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32541369/postgresql-are-my-indexes-or-column-types-slowing-down-my-query#comment52939976_32541369). `integer` is smaller and cheaper to sort. If you don't need `customername` in the result, replace it with `customerid` completely.

A multicolumn index can help (like [@wildplasser commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32541369/postgresql-are-my-indexes-or-column-types-slowing-down-my-query#comment52941547_32541369)). If it's a (mostly) read-only table, a "covering" index that allows index-only scans would be even faster - especially if included columns are small:

```
CREATE INDEX orders_nbr_idx ON orders (customerid, orderdate, orderid);
```

Adding `orderid` to the index only makes sense if you get index-only scans out of it. If you need the `customername`, add that, too. More:

- [How does PostgreSQL perform ORDER BY if a b-tree index is built on that field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576669/how-does-postgres-perfom-order-by-if-a-b-tree-index-is-built-on-that-field/31577208#31577208)

If it's (mostly) a read-only table, execute the expensive query once and save the snapshot as [**`MATERIALIZED VIEW`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rules-materializedviews.html) for reuse ...

#### Peanuts

You can do a couple of small things to reduce the memory footprint. After [playing column tetris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966524/calculating-and-saving-space-in-postgresql/7431468#7431468), this would save 0-7 bytes per row currently lost to padding:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  orderid integer,
  customerid integer,
  amount money,
  tax money,
  orderdate date,
  status text,
  customername text,
  customerstate text
  );
```

If you write the result to another table (or `MATERIALIZED VIEW`), it would save a bit to optimize the query in a similar fashion. `rank()` produces a `bigint`, by casting to `int` you save 8 bytes per row (4 + 4 padding):

```
SELECT orderid, customername, orderdate
    -- orderid, customerid, orderdate  -- good enough?
     , rank() OVER (PARTITION BY customerid
                    ORDER BY orderdate)::int AS cust_ord_nbr
FROM   orders;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on materialized view! Going to try that out and report back.