# Find intersection with given list

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of files paths with hashes of its content, there could be multiple files with the same hash.

```
create table files(
  path varchar(256) not null,
  hash varchar(100) not null
);

create index files_hash on files (hash);
```

Given I have array of 3 hashes `'a', 'b', 'c'`, how can I find **efficiently** which of those hashes the `files` table contains?

I can use `select distinct hash` to get hashes that exist in `files`:

```
select distinct hash
from   files
where  hash in ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

But would it be efficient? Like say there are hundreds of thousands of files with hash `'a'`, would PostgreSQL iterate over all those records? Is there a way to tell it to stop immediately as soon as it finds the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as fast as it gets:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   unnest('{a,b,c}'::varchar[]) AS arr(hash)
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT FROM files f WHERE f.hash = arr.hash);
```

If your table is `VACUUM`'ed enough, you get an index-only scan on your `files_hash` index with constant (excellent) performance, no matter how many hashes match. See:

- [Postgres not using index when index scan is much better option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537096/postgres-not-using-index-when-index-scan-is-much-better-option/34584053#34584053)
- [How does PostgreSQL perform ORDER BY with a b-tree index on the field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576669/how-does-postgresql-perform-order-by-with-a-b-tree-index-on-the-field/31577208#31577208)

Answer (score 1):

If you want all hashes from an array, I would suggest:

```
select distinct hash
from files
where hash = any(array['a', 'b', 'c']);
```

For performance on this query, you want an index on `files(hash)`.

If you only want one returned, then this should be faster:

```
select hash
from files
where hash = any(array['a', 'b', 'c'])
limit 1;
```