# PostgreSQL "likes" table design - selecting in order of incrementing ID is optimal?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, database-design, postgresql-performance

I’m brand new to SQL today and I'm designing a sole table which will be used to load likes of a post, in order, `n` at a time. Ex: Load the first 10 likes for a post, later load the next 10, etc.

I'm curious if this table design and query will be optimal? (All other data is in a NoSQL database ~ total count of likes is not needed).

To be more specific; will `ORDER BY likeID` and `WHERE likeID > (starting point)` slow down the query or use unnecessary resources? (the likeID will auto-increment, but some likes may be deleted/removed from the table at some point. There may be millions of likes recorded in this table).

The `postLikes` table:

```
postID: string
userID: string
username: string
timestamp: int
likeID: uniqueID (int) - increments every like
```

A user loads the first 2 likes for a post:

```
SELECT username, userID, likeID 
FROM postLikes 
WHERE (postID = “a1b767eae” AND likeID > 0)
ORDER BY likeID ASC 
LIMIT 2

returns:
[
   {username: "user6", userID: "SHi29s29", likeID: 324},
   {username: "user33", userID: "bsSU4s83", likeID: 1089}
]
```

Then the user loads the next two likes for the same post:

```
...

WHERE (postID = “a1b767eae” AND likeID > 1089)
ORDER BY likeID ASC LIMIT 2

returns:
[
   {username: "user8", userID: "Bsh292he", likeID: 2934},
   {username: "user543", userID: "sjXks28S", likeID: 10354}
]
```

Comment: Looks like a piece of cake for postgreSQL.

Comment: Looks mostly OK to me. You might consider using OFFSET in conjunction with LIMIT to page through results so you don't have to keep track of the likeID. See docs [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pivotal ingredient for performance will be a matching [multicolumn index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html):

```
CREATE INDEX ON post_likes (post_id, like_id);
```

With index columns in this order. See:

- [Multicolumn index and performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33220/3684)
- [SQL syntax term for 'WHERE (col1, col2) < (val1, val2)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981903/sql-syntax-term-for-where-col1-col2-val1-val2/32982895#32982895)
- [Optimize query with OFFSET on large table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110504/optimize-query-with-offset-on-large-table/34291099#34291099)

If the only other column in the `SELECT` list will be `username`, consider a covering index (requires Postgres 11 or later) like:

```
CREATE INDEX ON post_likes (post_id, like_id) INCLUDE (username);
```

And keep your table vacuumed to allow [index-only scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html). See:

- [How does PostgreSQL perform ORDER BY with a b-tree index on the field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576669/how-does-postgresql-perform-order-by-with-a-b-tree-index-on-the-field/31577208#31577208)
- [Postgres not using index when index scan is much better option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537096/postgres-not-using-index-when-index-scan-is-much-better-option/34584053#34584053)

Oh, and don't use CaMeL-case identifiers in Postgres. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)